# 'In vs 'of' which one to use?

Tags: grammar

I have a sentence which I am very confused about which one is correct:

"Currently they are also the market leader **in** digital marketing **of** The Netherlands."

Other possibilities:

"Currently they are also the market leader **in** digital marketing **in** The Netherlands."

"Currently they are also the market leader **of** digital marketing **in** The Netherlands."

Kind regards

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to say. Please use the [edit] link to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand the confusion. Each sentence is slightly different and it's not very easy to see why. The first sentence is the most different in my opinion. 'Of' makes it seem like the Netherlands is being marketed by the company, as opposed to the company being the leader of marketing in the Netherlands.

The second sentence is right on the money as far as getting the point across is concerned. I assume the point of the sentence is to say that the company is the most prominent digital marketing company in the Netherlands. I'm also assuming 'they' is referring to a company, however, that isn't really important.

The third sentence is slightly off the point. The 'of' makes it seem as though the company is the leader of digital marketing in the same way an alpha wolf is the leader of a wolf pack. In other words, it seems like they make the rules on how digital marketing is to allowed to be done.

The use of 'of' in these cases indicates what is being acted on. "Currently they are also the market leader in digital marketing of The Netherlands." The Netherlands is being marketed by the market leader. "Currently they are also the market leader of digital marketing in The Netherlands." They are leading digital marketing.

'In' is just indicating where the action is happening. "Currently they are also the market leader in digital marketing in The Netherlands." Where are they leading digital marketing? In the Netherlands. Where are they leading in the Netherlands? Are they leading in basketball, sales, labor, what? They are leading in digital marketing.